# Is there a cross-browser method to bring a popup window into the foreground?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, focus

I have a chat in a popup browser window. This chat page (ASP) checks for new messages every 10 seconds.

I would like to bring this popup window  to front when there is a new message. I tried with "window.focus()", but this work only in few version of IE.

Are there other options to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Don't steal the focus](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001011.html).

And no, it will work only in some IEs, as you said. Quoting [Mozilla's developer network](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.focus),

> It may fail due to user settings and
>   the window isn't guaranteed to be
>   frontmost before this method returns.

This is valid for all modern browsers, I guess.

You can use the [following approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37122/make-browser-window-blink-in-task-bar) in order to notify the user of an activity.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way out. You can use the JavascriptExecutor class to get the hidden browser and switch to it. This will bring the browser to the foreground.

```
String window = driver.getWindowHandle();
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("alert('Test')");
 driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
 driver.switchTo().window(window);
```