# How to illuminate a browser window/tab when something interesting happens in the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, notifications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make Browser Window Blink in Task Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37122/make-browser-window-blink-in-task-bar)

Hello

I want to notify that something interesting has happened in a web page which is in a browser window or a tab.

Eg. In Gmail chat, if you are in a different tab/window and if some one pings you in the chat the tab glows and shows some description running.

How to do that in Javascript/JQuery?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NLV - one way to do this would be to have a setInterval() running against an ajax method on your base page (which all other pages are inherited from) which gets initialised in the $(window).ready event. the method inside the setInterval() would poll for your interesting updates via the ajax call and if anything of interest was found, then a div would be added to the page flow which had a link to the relevant interesting new content (it could roll down in a similar way to the stackoverflow div that rolls down from the top if you've earned a new badge etc).

that would be my approach to the problem.

jim

Comment: I have no problem trapping the event of interesting updates. I want to make the tab or window containing the page blink. Like the one in Gmail chat when a user sends a message and you are in different tab or window.

Comment: I need to do that too, but I have no idea where to start looking for the solution.