# make my browser blink as indicator

Tags: javascript, jquery

My coworker wrote a quick mvc chat  application so we can chat about work stuff without leaving our desks.

What are some ways to indicate to each other a new message has been posted? My first thought was make the browser title bar flash. Anyone know how?

Comment: Why not use a native chat application? Not installed?

Comment: @Marcel Korpel, The web is the future!

Comment: How about using the BLINK tag? /ducks

Comment: Why re-invent the wheel and not just use IRC?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make Browser Window Blink in Task Bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37122/make-browser-window-blink-in-task-bar)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not possible to make the browser blink in javascript.
A possibility is to set the document title to empty an then write it again with through a period of time with *setTimeout()*

Comment: +1. This is similar to what many web-based chat applications do. They often simulate a message scrolling on the title bar.

Answer (score 5):

You could [**play a tone or other audio clip**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879152/how-do-i-make-javascript-beep) when a new message displays.

The nice thing about an audible cue is that you are able to keep your eyes on your work until you come to a natural break point to answer the message. Visual cues, in my opinion, are more likely to interrupt your work flow.

Obviously you can make the audible cue as pleasant and non-intrusive as your imagination allows.

Comment: Ow; my ears!  I thought we had gotten rid of all those unnecessary sounds on the Web.

Answer (score 2):

This nifty function i got reserved should be handy:

It changes the title of the page to alert the user, and returns the function that will stop the interval(i.e. on a `window.onmousemove` listener).

```
function Alert(msg [, ti]) { 
// msg = the message, ti= time interval between title changes(default is 1.5s)
    var intervalId, oldTitle = document.title;
    intervalId = setInterval(function(){
        document.title = document.title == msg ? oldTitle : msg;
    }, ti ? ti : 1500);
    return function() {
    if(oldTitle) {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
        document.title = oldTitle;
    oldTitle = intervalId = null;
    }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've written a [jQuery plugin](http://heyman.info/jquery-title-alert/) for this purpose. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37122/make-browser-window-blink-in-task-bar/3886467#3886467) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37122/make-browser-window-blink-in-task-bar/3886467).