# Javascript notification solution library: desktop, audible, popup, titlebar blinking, etc

Tags: javascript, html, notifications

Are there any Javascript libraries supporting notifications at the end of a long running operation, such as upload? Preferably the notifications would be universal, so that if certain technologies don't work, like desktop notifications, the browser still manages to get attention.

- Audible bell
- Desktop notification (Chrome)
- Stackoverflow.com style top slider pop-up
- Title bar blinking

Comment: Possible duplicates?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37122/make-browser-window-blink-in-task-bar and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5249692/flash-the-title-bar

Comment: Or should I say, possible solutions... they are related to the Titlebar blinking part, but not the other three.

Answer (score 1):

Mac OS growl kind of jQuery Plugin is available here

http://thrivingkings.com/sticky/