# Force minimized IE blink with Javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make Browser Window Blink in Task Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37122/make-browser-window-blink-in-task-bar)

Hi,

with Javascript help, i want to force IE to blink when in taskbar. Blink means trying to get focus. Function `alert()` helps for Firefox, but not IE.

P.s. Would be nice avoiding new window creation and activeX.

IE versions: 6,7,8.

Any Ideas?

Comment: @Marcel Korpel thanks, i will test if it gives me what i want.

Answer (score 0):

Marcel Korpel's link was usefull.

Function `window.focus()` solves the problem.