# How to put a blue point like Gmail in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, css, gmail, favicon

When I receive a new email, chrome put a blue point after gmail favicon. How Can I do this for my website when a new message arrives?

[image: like this]

Note: I test and understand that gmail doesn't do this using changing favicon. It does something else.

[image: proof]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing website favicon dynamically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/260857/changing-website-favicon-dynamically)

Comment: @Theraot gmail doesn't do this by changing favicon. I test it..

Comment: @Theraot favicon is static during this event.

Comment: I had a look at Chromium source. They call it an [indicator](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/browser/ui/views/tabs/tab.cc?q=tab.cc+package:%5Echromium$&dr=C&l=1257) and it is not part of the [favicon](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/browser/ui/views/tabs/tab.cc?q=tab.cc+package:%5Echromium$&dr=C&l=1239). I'm unaware of what triggers it. Yet, it appears to only be used for pinned tabs. I'm retracting my close vote. Edit: it is changint the title of the tab what triggers it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you put the blue dot on pinned Chrome tabs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825680/how-do-you-put-the-blue-dot-on-pinned-chrome-tabs) - can't vote to close again, ha!

Comment: @Theraot WOWWWW!! tnx..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Apparently tabs flash automatically when you change the title.
>   [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4827859/4107888)

Answer (score 1):

You should evaluate [favicon.js](http://lab.ejci.net/favico.js/). This JS framework lets you change the favicon and also supports numbered notifications. There is a live demo right in the home page, so you will know immediately if it fits your needs.