# Webapp that causes browser to issue an alert?

Tags: alert, irc

I am not sure exactly how to ask this question as I am not sure of the terminology I should use. I am writing a web application that is essentially a browser based IRC client. I wish to replicate some functionality I see in clients like x-chat where when you get a personal message it will alert the window manager. In my window manager (Aweosme wm) it turns the program tab red, in windows I imagine it would cause the programs button on the task bar to blink.

Essentially it's a notification that tells the window manager that something has happened and the program wants your attention.

- What is the terminology for this
  functionality?
- Is it possible to
  make a webapp tell the browser to do
  this?
- If 'B' is yes then how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really make your browser window blink in the task bar. For HTML5 a Notification API was planned and so far Chrome [supports](http://onepixelahead.com/2010/05/31/html5-notification-example/) it, but it seems that it was [dropped](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-diff/) again.

The only cross-browser possibilities to get the attention of your users are either to set the focus of the window:

```
window.focus();
```

or to change the title of your page:

```
document.title = "New message!";
```

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37122/make-browser-window-blink-in-task-bar/156274#156274) SO answer for a nice "blinky" implementation of changing `document.title`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an API to use notifications in webapps. Just because there are a lot of different notification systems in different OS (Growl in Mac OS X, system tray notifications in MS Windows and several window managers API in Linux). In Mac OS X and Linux, by default, you don't have any notification system installed.