# How to open a window (message) above all open browser tabs?

Tags: javascript, browser

The user waits for a message. But it may open another browser windows or tabs, or even other programs. How best to signal the presence of new messages by using JS?

Comment: can u tell with some example.?

Comment: Examples abound. Like advertising pop-up windows on Web sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){alert("test");})
or
window.onload=function(){alert("test")};
```

if your given your ad or anything whatever u want, it will be display. i dont know whether you want this one r not..?

Comment: Thank you Sakthi, i now it method. 
I generally make a flash application - an online consultation with experts. The client must select an expert from the list and an expert should see a message that he call for a chat. Naturally, the expert can not always look at the app window, he can open another browser window or even open another program. But i must somehow quickly inform the expert that he was invited to chat. If within 20-30 seconds the expert does not respond, the client can go out.

Comment: if your doing a separate application like gtalk, its possible. otherwise u can do like facebook chat. if the msg came, u can make a blink or notify in that particular tab. and i think its possible to show like gtalk from the browser..

Comment: Yes, this is what I need. Are there any examples?

Comment: this may useful for you..                                    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37122/make-browser-window-blink-in-task-bar