# Need to open popup in foreground

Tags: asp.net

I'm writing a process to alert the users when their session is about to end. I want a popup window (or alert) to appear, and I've got that much working, but more importantly I want them to be alerted even when their browser is in the background - either by having the popup come right to the foreground - on top of any other application, Or having their browser window flash in the taskbar.
Any ideas or suggestions how to do this?  Is there maybe a property of the AJAX popup extender that controls this?
Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't put a popup in front of another application, however you can make the tab / title  "blink" until they take notice.

Take a look at this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/156274/935779

It is a JavaScript solution that may help.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Kirk. I got the blinking working fine.  See my comment under John Mc for my question about making the change more attention-getting.  -Paul

Comment: I don't believe you'll be able to make any extra changes to the title bar to get attention. The title bar is a browser / OS thing rather than a HTML thing. You're limited in a browser to what you can do because of this. The only other thing you could do is make a non-browser addon, such as an executable that checks for updates and notifies the user that route

Answer (score 0):

A modal popup would be best for this. You don't need AJAX as you're not posting to the server.

Are you using jQuery? If so you can quickly and easily set up a timer which shows a modal dialogue box when the time expires.

On each page load, or on specific user actions you can reset the timer.

As for having the browser flash in the taskbar, I don't believe that's possible.

Comment: Hi, @Kirk, I did get the blinking title working - thanks for that. I just hope that the end-users will be satisfied with that. One more question - is there any way to bring even more attention to the title-bar, such as changing the font color or title background color?  I could not get the font color to change using document.title.fontcolor = 'red'. <br />. Thanks!  Paul

Comment: Sorry, meant this comment for @John Mc