# Make chrome icon on windows taskbar glow when chrome is minimized

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

On google chrome, when an `alert()` is activated and chrome is minimized there is an instance that the chrome icon on the taskbar glows orange (windows 7) sometimes the whole browser maximizes.

Is it possible to activate that glowing feature with javascript?

I need this for our office. I want the chrome icon to glow when its minimized and the user received a new message.

Thanks!

Comment: how about using http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/notifications/quick/. This question may be similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37122/make-browser-window-blink-in-task-bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I needed was a tactic that can get the users attention when they receive a new message while the browser is minimized. I couldn't find a way for the icon on the task bar to blink but I found an alternative that still fills the need. @HariKrishnan gave a link that led to a couple of googling that made me discover [Web Notifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/notifications/). You can find a very simple tutorial [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/bobleah/entry/html5_code_example_of_notifications81?lang=en).

Cheers!

---

For future reference I added the tut here since its just a two step process . .

**Step 1**

Ask user to allow webkitNotifications (Same thing with the html5 geolocation)

```
function askPermission(){
    webkitNotifications.requestPermission(testNotification);
}
```

**Step 2**

Creating a notification

```
function testNotification(){    
    var notification = webkitNotifications.createNotification('IMAGE','TITLE','BODY');
    notification.show();
}
```

(**Note:** Multiple notifications will stack)

Answer (score 0):

I found this piece of code, can't test is right now because i'm not using windows, but you should give it a try.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Flashing TaskBar
    setInterval(flashToolbar, 10000);    // calls flashToolbar every 10000 ms

    function flashToolbar() {
        if (window.external.msIsSiteMode()) {
            window.external.msSiteModeActivate();
        }
    }
</script>
```

source: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jennifer/archive/2011/05/10/ie-pinned-sites-part-8-how-to-implement-a-flashing-taskbar-button.aspx

Comment: not working on chrome. I made a quick search and I think its IE only? The office browsers are all chrome so I kinda need it to be chrome compatible. Thanks though. .