# How to make browser tab active for my website or maximized when its minimized

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend, browser-tab

I am building order dashboard for client, is there any way that when client browser window is minimized or tab is not active, I want to show tab tab active and maximized if its already minimized.

Ajax call run after 30 seconds and check for new orders, if new order fetched, I want to do the above actions. help me if there is any quick solution using javascript. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37122/make-browser-window-blink-in-task-bar

Comment: You can't control browser app within OS from within a page window. Think about it a bit. Would you want  websites you visit to start moving and resizing apps  on your screen at will? Or keep jumping from tab to tab within browser? Take a look at Notifications API

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "I want to show tab tab active and maximized if its already minimized".  If you want to notify a user that something has happened even while the page is minimized, consider using the [Notification API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification).

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, just use `window.focus();`