# How to blink browser tab on receiving message from other user using pusher chatkit notification

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, pusher, chatkit

I need plain JavaScript sample code to blink tab when user send message using Chatkit and receiver is not viewing the tab at that time. (Chatkit push notification)

Comment: you can blink the title on and off and remove the blink on `onmousemove ` try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37122/make-browser-window-blink-in-task-bar) answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make blinking/flashing text with CSS 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16344354/how-to-make-blinking-flashing-text-with-css-3)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack overflow. We are not here to code your project but to help you resolving problems. You could provide what you tried so far, why your code does not work properly ?

Comment: @PGill it's working thanks buddy.. :)